# #1064 - SQL syntax Error while trying to import

Tags: mysql, mariadb, import

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `migration_versions`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `migration_versions` (
  `version` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

is giving me this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */' at line 5

This is the original (unedited) exported statement. The only thing I did was change collations to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `migration_versions`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `migration_versions` (
  `version` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: **#1.** Does non-edited script executes successfully? **#2.** Does this script (dump) is obtained from the database posessed on the MySQL server? What are precise versions of src and dst servers? **#3.** Try to import original file then alter the table and change column/table collations with additional ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: @Akina I am able to import the original/unaltered w/out issue. Original server that exported: `Server version: 10.3.23-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server`, and server being imported into: `Server version: 10.8.3-MariaDB-1:10.8.3+maria~jammy-log - mariadb.org binary distribution`

Comment: This looks like your destination server is hosted on .nix whereas you have edited the file using the editor on Windows which results in line terminators mixing (both LF and CR/LF are present).. or something similar. If you have some HEX viewer then look at the bytes immediately before the SET statement which is citated in the error message. Also ensure that the edited file is NOT saved as utf with BOM.

Comment: @Akina I have to admit, that's pretty astute that you noticed that, lol. You're correct, but it was all one line originally, and I just pasted the version above to make it easier to read here on SE. A single line that long can get a bit annoying to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Create Table statement needs to be terminated with a semi-colon (*after* your new Collation sequence).

The `40101` comments will be included or not based on your DBMS version.
In this case, they're clearly *being* included, so your script is effectively this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `migration_versions`;

SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;

SET character_set_client = utf8;

CREATE TABLE `migration_versions` (
  `version` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`version`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci 
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

Without the statement terminator, it's trying to treat the Set statement as just another clause in the Create Table statement.